# Create COM-Object from own C# Dll in Progress 4GL

Tags: c#, com, progress-4gl

I'm wondering how I can create a Com-Object from my own C# DLL.

I made the following Class in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ProgressNet
{
    [Guid("a9b1e34d-3ea3-4e91-a77a-5bcb25875485")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ProgId("ProgressNet.Server")]
    public class NetServer
    {
        public NetServer() {}

        [DispId(1)]
        public string GetString()
        {
            return "Some String";
        }
    }
}
```

In Properties I checked Register for COM Interop.

Then I registered the DLL with regasm.

```
regasm G:\ProgressTestApp\ProgressNet.dll /tlb:G:\ProgressTestApp\ProgressNet.tlb /codebase
```

Then I tried in Progress 4GL this Code:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE NetServer AS COM-HANDLE.
CREATE "ProgressNet.NetServer" NetServer.  
MESSAGE NetServer:GetString().
```

But then I get "The automation server for ProgressNet.NetServer is not registered properly"..

Any Suggestions? :)

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit.  The description of how you used regasm is not.

Comment: regasm G:\ProgressTestApp\ProgressNet.dll /tlb:G:\ProgressTestApp\ProgressNet.tlb

Comment: Add the /codebase option so you don't have to put the assembly in the GAC.

Comment: Hi man, How did you work for this code at the end?

Comment: @John I don't understand your question. What do you want to know? :)

Comment: How did you run the code?, I use Progress 9.1e, I made a DLL with C # code as following your model. When you import the DLL in "Progress" as COM shows me the functions created in the DLL which receive strings to call these functions I get an error when compiling my. P

Comment: @John Compile DLL, regasm, and then I ran the code inside a Procedure Window from the AppBuilder, we're running on Progress 10.1C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN case anyone is still reading this, the answer turns out to be pretty simple:  The following line is wrong.

```
MESSAGE NetServer::GetString().
```

It should be

```
MESSAGE NetServer:GetString().
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the `create` com-handle statement. It should be `create "ProgressNet.Server" NetServer.` and not `"ProgressNet.NetServer"` as specified by the `ProgId` call.

I registered the DLL with `regasm` as you mentioned and used the code below to test and it worked fine.

```
def var ch as com-handle no-undo.

create "ProgressNet.Server" ch.

MESSAGE ch:GetString()
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
```