# C# COM object access from Progress 4GL

Tags: c#, com, progress-4gl

This question was already asked previously as:

[Create COM-Object from own C# Dll in Progress 4GL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688009/create-com-object-from-own-c-sharp-dll-in-progress-4gl)

The question at that link was only partially answered, and I'm at the same stopping point.

Given the example at the link, has anyone ever gotten it working, and if so, how?
I've gotten as far as the person in the linked question.  The .Net based COM object has been registered correctly and recognized by the Progress 4GL, but when access is attempted, an "Invalid number of parameters" error occurs. The COM object methods are reported correctly by the Progress COM object viewer, so it SHOULD be accessible.

Is this even possible with Progress?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is an answer after all; I supplied it there, but the problem is OP used two colons instead of one in his method call.  Make that one change and the code works.