# .Net Core Interop Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I developed a Interop DLL using C# to be called by Progress 4GL.
I follow this example:
[Create COM-Object from own C# Dll in Progress 4GL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688009/create-com-object-from-own-c-sharp-dll-in-progress-4gl)

It worked on Windows, but the customer server is on Linux, so I changed my DLL to use .Net Core.

So, how can I call it on Linux? Do I need to register it? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Sorry, but what you want to _call_? Can you be more verbose with your question?

Comment: Please give a bit more details about what exactly are you trying to achieve here and how exactly you have tried.

Comment: It's the same thing that the example in the link.

Comment: I want to call a method that I created on C# through Progress 4GL

Comment: Venemo, as I don't know how to "register" a dll on Linux, I didn't try to call my method, because my dll isn't registered yet.

Comment: It's not possible to call .Net in Linux from Progress. See a more complete answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Progress has no support for .NET on Linux. It's Windows-only at this time, and no information about future support for .NET in Linux is available.

Perhaps you can develop the same feature in Progress 4GL instead - or create a Linux Shared Object without using .NET?

Here's a few links:
http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Does-OpenEdge-support-Net-Core

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Does-NET-Open-Client-support-Mono